# Regex for only allowing numbers with a letter to the right of them. Ex (1d 4h 32m)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am needing to test a duration input. The pattern should any number 1 or great plus any of these [\y\mo\d\h\m]. I need to require all numbers to be followed by one of those letters, a Letter grouping can only be in it once.

Valid examples would be:

- 1d 4h
- 1y 2mo 3h

Should fail on:

- 1
- 1d 4d
- mo q
- 1h 4

I've tried a few thing but none of them really get close. TBH I'm awful at regex's.

/\d[\y\mo\w\d\h\m]/

^^ that works for the first group.

Comment: Are duplicate units allowed (`1d 2d`)? Are missing units allowed (`1d 2mo`)?

Comment: Evidently my formatting is off. No, duplicate units should not be allowed. but missing units are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a negative lookahead `(?!` with a capturing group and a backreference `\1` to assert that what is captured does not occur twice:

```
^(?!.*\d+(y|mo|d|h|m).*\d\1)\d+(?:y|mo|d|h|m)(?: \d+(?:y|mo|d|h|m))*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\d+(y|mo|d|h|m).*\d+\1)` Assert what is on the right does not contain 2 times a digit followed by the same chars using a capturing group and backreference
- `\d+(?:y|mo|d|h|m)` Match 1+ digits follwed by one of the listed
- `(?: \d+(?:y|mo|d|h|m))*` Repeat the previous pattern 0+ times prepended with a space
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JsGWvV/1)